# Hibernate Query update

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate

I want to order the following query to hibernate query transform

```
UPDATE user_app SET score = score -500;
```

I wrote the query that is wrong and I get an error

```
int www = -500
Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE User  SET score = score + www");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `query.setParameter` for setting -500

```
Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE User  SET score = score + :www ");
query.setParameter("www",www);
```

For more info look at https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/

Comment: Thank
When I run the query had doubled or reduced . Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE User  SET score = score + :www ");
        query.setParameter("www",-1000);

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
Query query = session.createQuery("UPDATE User SET score = score + :score");
query.setParameter("score", www);
```

It's better to use parameters instead of string concatenation.